# r:coerce only character variables to factor while leaving other classes

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with over 40 variables of different classes.  About half of the variables are characters, however, I would like to coerce those variables to factor while leaving the integers, logicals, etc. as is.

I have tried using a an lapply function like the one below, but it coerces all variables instead of just the characters:

```
aframe2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(aframe1, factor))
```

I have also tried `as.data.frame(aframe1, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)` with no success.  Is there something I am doing wrong or some other function I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by using a `if/else` statement

```
aframe1[] <- lapply(aframe1, function(x) if(is.character(x)) factor(x) else x)
```

or create an index for `factor` columns and loop only on those columns

```
i1 <- sapply(aframe1, is.character)
aframe1[i1] <- lapply(aframe1[i1], factor)
```